# GCC C++17: variables declared inline not placed properly with __attribute__ ((section("xyz")))

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, c++17, inline

In C I am using

```
#ifdef my_fileC
#  define extint
#else
#  define extint extern
#endif
```

in headerfile my_file.h and then

```
extint int32_t my_var;
```

With C++17 I dropped extint and use inline:

```
inline int32_t my_var;
```

which normally works perfect. Now I used inline with variables that should be placed at predefined memory areas with attribute section:

```
inline int32_t my_var __attribute__ ((section("my_section")));
```

Unfortunatelly this does not produce the same results as using extint instead of inline. Only one variable is really placed in the desired section, the other ones are somewhere else, no compiler or linker error is given but the program crashes when reaching some point although the sources are the same except for inline replacing extint.

Anyone experienced this too? Is this a compiler or linker error or am I doing something wrong?
My project is pretty large so it is hard to reduce it to a minimalistic version that still has this error. I can provide map files of the project with only the attribute section variables using extint vs all variables using inline, if that gives more information.
I am using STM32 Cube IDE which has GNU tools 10.3-2021.10, compiling for STM32H7.

Thanks for any help.

Linker LD file for this section looks like this:

```
my_data_section (NOLOAD) :  /* (NOLOAD) forces not to create init data in hex file */
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);    
    *(my_section)  
    . = ALIGN(4);    
  } >RAM_D2
```

Comment: did you create `my_section` in the linker script? Or it is `.my_section` (usual naming convention)

Comment: yes, it is in the linker ld file where also the memory region is specified.

Comment: is it  `.mysection` or `mysection` without the dot

Comment: without the dot, see the edited question

Comment: try `KEEP(*(my_section*))`

Comment: I tried KEEP as you write, but no success, still the same result.

Comment: As I wrote, it is no problem with one variable per section, so I tried with one section per variable ie my_section_0, my_section_1 and so on and listed them all in the linker script file. This makes them all appear in the map file in my_data_section. So this is a workaround but not a nice one. Still looking for a better solution.

Comment: This workaround works with KEEP and without.

Comment: Did you notice that which section are used for the "other variables" ? Also, it would be good if you can share a small example that shows how you place the all variables in specific section.